# H2O Python API: retrieve best models from GridSearch

Tags: python, h2o

I am performing a GridSearch with H2O using the Python API using the following code,

```
from h2o.estimators.random_forest import H2ORandomForestEstimator
from h2o.grid import H2OGridSearch

hyper_parameters = {'ntrees':[10, 50, 100, 200], 'max_depth':[5, 10, 15, 20, 25], 'balance_classes':[True, False]}

search_criteria = {
    "strategy": "RandomDiscrete",
    "max_runtime_secs": 600,
    "max_models": 30,
    "stopping_metric": 'AUTO',
    "stopping_tolerance": 0.0001,
    'seed': 42
}

grid_search = H2OGridSearch(H2ORandomForestEstimator, hyper_parameters, search_criteria=search_criteria)
grid_search.train(x=events_names_x, 
                  y="total_rsvps", 
                  training_frame=train,
                  validation_frame=test)
```

Once run I want to print the models and predict in order of `AUC`,

```
grid_search.sort_by('auc', False)
```

I get the following error,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-272-b250bf2b838e> in <module>()
----> 1 grid_search.sort_by('auc', False)

/Users/stereo/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h2o/grid/grid_search.py in sort_by(self, metric, increasing)
    663 
    664         if metric[-1] != ')': metric += '()'
--> 665         c_values = [list(x) for x in zip(*sorted(eval('self.' + metric + '.items()'), key=lambda k_v: k_v[1]))]
    666         c_values.insert(1, [self.get_hyperparams(model_id, display=False) for model_id in c_values[0]])
    667         if not increasing:

/Users/stereo/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h2o/grid/grid_search.py in <module>()

/Users/stereo/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h2o/grid/grid_search.py in auc(self, train, valid, xval)
    606         :return: The AUC.
    607         """
--> 608         return {model.model_id: model.auc(train, valid, xval) for model in self.models}
    609 
    610     def aic(self, train=False, valid=False, xval=False):

/Users/stereo/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h2o/grid/grid_search.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
    606         :return: The AUC.
    607         """
--> 608         return {model.model_id: model.auc(train, valid, xval) for model in self.models}
    609 
    610     def aic(self, train=False, valid=False, xval=False):

/Users/stereo/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h2o/model/model_base.py in auc(self, train, valid, xval)
    669         tm = ModelBase._get_metrics(self, train, valid, xval)
    670         m = {}
--> 671         for k, v in viewitems(tm): m[k] = None if v is None else v.auc()
    672         return list(m.values())[0] if len(m) == 1 else m
    673 

/Users/stereo/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h2o/model/metrics_base.py in auc(self)
    158         :return: Retrieve the AUC for this set of metrics.
    159         """
--> 160         return self._metric_json['AUC']
    161 
    162     def aic(self):

KeyError: 'AUC'
```

Any advise on:

- can print the models in order of performance
- forecast with the model with the highest `AUC`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you need is

`sorted_grid = grid_search.get_grid(sort_by='auc',decreasing=True)
print(sorted_grid)`

you can change decreasing to False if you would prefer

Comment: So `auc` is apparently not supported anymore so had to do `mse` or `r2`. Thanks for the advise though!

Comment: Can we export these results somehow in a file?

Comment: auc should be supported as long as you are doing a binary classification problem, please make sure your target variable is an enum with `.asfactor()`  (you can find examples in the h2o user guid).

Comment: I don't think you can export the grid search object as a table, but you can get an individual model's information from the grid search table (h2o.get_model('<your model id>') and then export parts of those results to a file (anything that is type H2OFrame)